# How to edit multiple values from database in python flask form

Tags: python, mysql, flask

I've started learning programming in python sometime ago and I've decided to try and make small contract management tool using flask and mysql. I went through first part to manage customers, sellers and contracts but now I'm getting into more numerical stuff. I can easily work on single records from the database (where 1 record is for example customer details) but now I need to find out a way to edit 1 value (column) in multiple rows.

I have a database where delivery_period_start and delivery_period_end are just representing months (it's probably gonna be changed into single 2021-01-00 statement as I need only monthly values). The column I need to work on is a consumption of energy (profile_mw) that is different for each month. I need to have a form (using wtforms) that could be used to edit all values for all months for one customer (each customers data will be stored in separate tables).

I tried to look for solution for last three days but as I got stuck I've decided to ask you for help.

The code I tried to execute in flask is:

```
@app.route(site)
def profile_list():
tablename = "customer"

cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
profile = cur.execute("SELECT * FROM " + tablename)    
profile_list = cur.fetchall()

form = ProfileForm(request.form)
for d in profile_list:       
        form.profile.data = d['profile_mw']

return render_template('site.html', profile_list=profile_list, form=form)
```

Then I've created simple jinja2 code try and populate the data (I skip some previous code like formhelpers or div table):

```
{% for profile in profile_list %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{profile.delivery_period_start}} - {{profile.delivery_period_end}}</td>
         <td>{{ render_field(form.profile, class_="form-control") }}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Result that I get is a table with correct number of rows and stringfields (12 records in db = 12 rows = 12 fields), correct start-end delivery dates but the value I got in all fields is just last value from the table (12th profile_mw value from last row in table).

Could you please help me in getting proper values in the form (so I can get correct profile_mw value for months 1-12 respectively) and then how could I send eddited values to the database?

Thank you in advance for your support.

Comment: ´...but the value I got in all fields is just last value from the table..´  It doesn't surprise me you get 12 times the same value, you are printing the same variable (form.profile). What is in the form?

Comment: Hello @MennoHölscher and thank you for looking into this.

Form is very simple:

`class ProfileForm(Form):
    profile = StringField('')`

Should I simply create then a big form (for no.of years * 12 fields)? And if yes (I can easily work on this) how can I use this big form to edit all values at once? For single row edit I used "id" index addressing. How to do that for multiple rows?

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is the WTForms FieldList.Go to [the fields documentation](https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/2.3.x/fields/) and search for FieldList.

FieldList enables you to create more than one field with the same definition in a form. You need to supply the different values when creating the form and when the user submits the form you will get the values that were entered.

When the form is submitted you need to know what the values are for, in your case the client and the month. The simplest way is to put the client id and the first month as hidden fields in the form. You will get it back so you can retrieve the information you (may) need to change. You need that, because on `post` you do not know the information that you sent to the page previously.

That makes the form show up as:

```
>>> class ProfileForm(wf.Form):
...     client_id = wf.HiddenField()
...     first_month = wf.HiddenField()
...     month_figures = wf.FieldList(wf.IntegerField(), max_entries=12)
```